# Creating a table to get a count of values within a certain range

Tags: excel-formula, formula

[Frequency distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN5mT.png)

The formula I tried is as follows:
=IF($H4>=9900,1,0*(IF($H4>=10200,2,0)*IF($H4>=10500,3,0)*IF($H4>=10800,4,0)*IF($H4>=11100,5,0)*IF($H4>=11400,5,0)*IF($H4>11700,6,0)*IF($H4>=12000,6,0)))

I received output of (1) for all answers and I know that is not the truth.
The values I am trying to retrieve are in variables of 300 as shown above.

Comment: you seem to be multiplying 0 by the subsequent if statements and as soon as H4 is greater than 9900 it will return 1.  have you tried the countif() function?

Comment: Thank you that a great suggestion, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
[image]

Countif formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<="&D3)
```